# Use macro donw the rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a problem with setting up a macro. Let me try to explain:
I've got two sheets, in sheet1 I've got pure data, in sheet2 I've got a macro that calculates how many pieces you can put into a certain container by using dimensions given in certain cells. As I said I've got a pure data in sheet1 which contains a box number, its width, length a container number its going to be packed and that container's width and length. Now what I want is I want the macro to copy the dims from sheet1, put them in the specific cells in sheet2, run the calculating macro, copy the cell with result, paste it in the sheet1 and carry on with the next row until there's no data in the column next to it.

This what I've got so far but I don't know how to loop it for the next rows. I think there might be something with selecting cells that will make this possible rather then specifying the cells by name. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub AutoCalculating()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste


    Call CalculateBoxes


    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I did the code by offsets not by named cells and then looped it down until it finds an empty cell in the next row. Here's the is the code if somebody would struggle with such thing like I did. You just need to make sure before playing this macro we need to make active the first cell in the first empty column next to the data

```
Sub AutoCalc2()

Do
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then

Exit Do

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Copy 1st cell which is +5 cells to the left next to the acive

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Copy 2nd cell which is +4 Cells to the left next to the acive

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B4").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Copy 3rd cell which is +2 cells to the left next to the acive

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Range("B5").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        'Copy 4th cell which is +1 cells to the left next to the acive

     Call CalculateBoxes
     'Call your macro

Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("B6").Select
ActiveCell.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'selects next cell to be active so it won't make it lasts forever block on first cell
End If
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: `activecell` is any cell that you happen to click on while the code is running. ... you macro will fail catastrophically unless a specific cell is selected when you run the code. you need to get rid of all the `select ... activecell` code and refer to cells by their fully qualified name

Comment: @jsotola You are absolutely right and in the first place I've just put a large inscription to select a specific cell before clicking the macro but then I've updated it with this code which is finding and selecting first empty cell in selected column(in this case column 8 which means column H)
'
Sub EmptyCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(8).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell
    
Call AutoCalc2
End Sub
'

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, here's the code

`Sub EmptyCell()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(8).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell
    
Call AutoCalc2
End Sub`